How do I stop my tkinter animation from disappearing at the end of my loop?
As the title states, how do I stop the images in an animation made in tkinter from disappearing?
I have my code here:
ballx1 = 100
bally1 = 500
speed=10

for frames in range(300):
    rectangle = s.create_rectangle(ballx1,bally1,ballx1+100,bally1+200,fill='red')
    s.update()
    sleep(0.0333)
    s.delete(rectangle)
    if(bally1 >= 600):
        speed=speed * -1
    if bally1<=0:
        speed=speed * -1
    bally1=bally1-speed

How would I prevent the screen from going black at the end of the loop?
I have attempted altering the delete line to this,
if frames<=299:
        s.delete(rectangle)

, but the screen still goes black in the end.

frames<=299 will always be true, here - range(300) produces numbers from zero to 299.  Change the comparison to <, or the number to 298, and this should work.

You should create the rectangle once and move it inside the for loop. However it is better to use .after() instead of for loop and sleep().

You should not create and delete the rectangle to move it.  Instead create the rectangle once and just move it inside the for loop using .coords():
# create the rectangle
rectangle = s.create_rectangle(ballx1, bally1, ballx1+100, bally1+200, fill='red')

for frame in range(300):
    s.update()
    sleep(0.0333)
    if bally1 >= 600 or bally1 <= 0:
        speed *= -1
    bally1 -= speed
    # move the rectangle
    s.coords(rectangle, ballx1, bally1, ballx1+100, bally1+200)

However it is not recommended to use for loop and sleep() in a tkinter application because it will block the tkinter mainloop() from handling pending events and updates.  Better use after loop instead.
rectangle = s.create_rectangle(ballx1, bally1, ballx1+100, bally1+200, fill='red')

def animation(bally, speed, n=300):
    if n >= 0:
        if bally >= 600 or bally <= 10:
            speed *= -1
        bally -= speed
        s.coords(rectangle, ballx1, bally, ballx1+100, bally+200)
        s.after(33, animation, bally, speed, n-1)

# start the animation
animation(bally1, speed)

